# Attaching User to Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, comments

I have a working commenting system that is polymorphic so that comments can be added to **users** and **posts**. However, I am unable to figure out how to attach the logged in user (commenter) to the comment.

comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:create, :destroy]

def index
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comments = @commentable.comments
end

def new
    @commentable = find_commentable
end

def create
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
    redirect_to get_master
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end

protected

def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end

def get_master
    @parent = @comment.commentable
    if @parent.respond_to?('commentable_type')
      @comment = @parent
      get_master
    else
      return @parent
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as adding it before the `save`?

```
@comment.commenter = current_user
```

You can also add it in your view:

```
f.hidden_field :commenter_id, value: current_user.id
```

I think I'd prefer setting it in the view.